# Setting Basic authorization details in request headers

Tags: javascript, java

In our application we validate user name/password. Once validation is done, credentials are encoded using base64 and then needs to be set at request header for subsequent rest calls.

Need to set below in request header.

```
Authorization:Basic AQNLzR69OFTNJE8X
```

In the response setting as below from the java code,

```
javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(200).entity("").header("Authorization:","Basic AQNLzR69OFTNJE8X").build();
```

And in the javascript tried setting as below,

```
sessionStorage.setItem('Authorization:', 'Basic AQNLzR69OFTNJE8X');
```

But in the subsequent rest service calls in the same session can see the header request is not set with authorization. Request to provide some pointers on setting the Authorization in javascript, so that it is retained for the entire session.

Comment: Are you trying to do authentication or authorization? I feel like you are mixing the two here.

Comment: The correct name of the header is `Authorization`.  It should **not** contain a colon (`:`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how authentication works (or should work).
You are supposed to send the `Authorization` header only once during the authentication. If the authentication is successful, the server sends you back a session cookie and your session is marked as authenticated (server-side).
You never send back the content of the header, and you don't have to send it each request.

1) The `Authorization` header is not automatically added. But the cookie will be automatically sent.

2) You should not send the credential and return them: for security purposes, you want to transport them the less you can.

3) You don't want to store the credential in the sessionStorage, I don't know if this is a secure place for a password (i doubt it), but here, the password is only encoded in B64, and it's reversable. So it's as well as cleartext (which is bad for a password).

Hopes this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I got the credentials validated from server. Can you please clarify on below points, 1. How to send back session cookie from server. 2. How the cookie will be automatically sent. Any pointer to existing materials or code will be helpful.

Comment: 1) The server sends back the cookie to the client using the `Set-Cookie` header. Depending on your server, this could be done automatically. If you perform the authentication yourself, just make sure that you save in the user session who he is (his `Principal`)
2) That's the basic of any web browser. Any cookie you have is automatically sent each request if the request matches the domain and the path of the request.